# Как стороннему потоку сказать главному, что он завершился?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вопрос вызван тем, что у меня есть `CyclicBarrier`, и мне из главного потока нужно узнать, когда `CyclicBarrier` открылся. Для `CyclicBarrier` я могу указать `Runnable`, который выполнится, когда барьер откроется:

```
CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, () -> {/*здесь*/});
```

В главном потоке я запускаю все потоки(3), связанные с `CyclicBarrier`, и жду, допустим, 12 секунд.
Теперь возможны две ситуации:
1) Барьер уже открыт
2) Барьер еще закрыт
Так, теперь встает интересная проблема:
Мы не можем сделать сразу `cyclicBarrier.await()`, так как если 1), то мы застрянем навечно. Если мы сделаем проверку(`getNumberWaiting() == 0`), и только потом сделаю `cyclicBarrier.await()`, то есть вероятность, что барьер откроется в аккурат между этими операциями.
Есть ли атомарный способ решить проблему?

Comment: А вам нужна эта цикличность барьера?
Просто если нет, то вам бы CountDownLatch подошел для этих целей, если конечно я уловил суть того, что вы хотите сделать. Просто у CountDownLatch метод await [работает несколько иначе](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) - так, как нужно вам.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, подходит(если await() сразу выкинет, если счётчик закончился), но можно ли в теории повернуть такой финт с ушами, но с CyclicBarrier? Практический задачи предо мной не стоит. Но этот момент важен для понимания границ применения. CountDownLatch несколько раз то не использовать.

Comment: я так понимаю, что вы хотите оставить CyclicBarrier ради callback'а в виде Runnable? В случае использования CountDownLatch такое можно провернуть, хоть и менее элегантно - следующей строчкой после вызова await.

Comment: @StateIsPrimitive тогда уж проще поток отдельный прицепить (не все же ожидающие должны вызывать Runnable). Что я хочу понять - как решить "интересную проблему"? Первое, что приходит на ум - это сделать Exchanger с объектом-заглушкой - но это, считаю, костыль.

Comment: Если очень хотите продолжить использовать CyclicBarrier, то можно, попробовать так: 1) в вашем callback'е (Runnable) можно попробовать намеренно перевести барьер в "broken state", а в основном потоке усердно проверять isBroken() 2) завести volatile boolean / AtomicBoolean поле, которое выставлять в true только при достижении барьера (в вашем callback'е), а в основном методе до посинения проверять значение :) 3) вместо boolean использовать какой-нибудь примитив синхронизации (тут надо подумать какой лучше). Как видите все решения не слишком элегантные :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive все сводится к проверке до посинения - читай, замена wait. Постараюсь завтра углубленней поискать, может, что найду. Проблема то должна быть распространенной.

Comment: Накину еще пару костыльных вариантов: 1) вместо циклического барьера использовать new Semaphore(3), в каждом запускаемом потоке делать его acquire(), а в основном смотреть не ноль ли availablePermits() 2) завести поле типа new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1), а в callback'е CyclicBarrier'а класть (через offer()) туда что-нибудь, а в основном потоке ждать когда там что-нибудь появится через блокирующий вызов метода take().

Comment: @StateItPrimitive придумал! Можно синхронизировать и notify в Runnable, и "if(getNumberWaiting() == 0) wait()". Тогда, как только выполнится условие(Runnable будет ждать), начнет выполняться и wait(), который, как мы знаем, освобождает монитор и ждет, пока Runnable не вызовет notify. Все, что нужно, - это объект-заглушка.

Comment: Но ведь тогда остается интервал времени между проверкой "if(getNumberWaiting() == 0)" (что, кстати говоря, неоднозначно, т.к. может говорить либо о том, что ни один из "await()" еще не был вызван, либо что уже вызваны все 3 и он опять обнулился) и непосредственным вызовом "wait()". За этот интервал времени все другие потоки могли успеть исполниться, как следствие вызвался callback (твой Runnable), который как следствие мог вызвать "notify()" на объекте, хотя для него еще не был вызван "wait()", как следствие падение по "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException" в месте вызова "notify()".

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Добавил ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `synchronized` и `wait`/`notify`

(+ `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` и `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SynchronizedHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AtomicBoolean isBarrierBroken = new AtomicBoolean();

        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, () -> {
            synchronized (isBarrierBroken) {
                isBarrierBroken.set(true);
                isBarrierBroken.notify();
            }
        });
        new DoSomethingAndWait("1", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("2", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("3", cyclicBarrier).start();

        // закомментировать строчку, если захочешь,
        // чтобы поменялся порядок выполнения wait() и notify()
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        synchronized (isBarrierBroken) {
            if (!isBarrierBroken.get()) {
                System.out.println("main thread waits");
                isBarrierBroken.wait();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("main thread ends");
    }

    private static class DoSomethingAndWait extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

        DoSomethingAndWait(String name, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s works%n", name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // do work
                System.out.printf("%s waits%n", name);
                cyclicBarrier.await();
                System.out.printf("%s ends%n", name);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Через `java.util.concurrent.Lock` и `java.util.concurrent.Condition`

(+ `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier` и `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`):

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class ConcurrentLockHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        AtomicBoolean isBarrierBroken = new AtomicBoolean();

        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, () -> {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                isBarrierBroken.set(true);
                condition.signal();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        });

        new DoSomethingAndWait("1", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("2", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("3", cyclicBarrier).start();

        // закомментировать строчку, если захочешь,
        // чтобы поменялся порядок выполнения await() и signal()
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        try {
            lock.lock();
            if (!isBarrierBroken.get()) {
                System.out.println("main thread awaits");
                condition.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        System.out.println("main thread ends");
    }

    private static class DoSomethingAndWait extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

        DoSomethingAndWait(String name, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s works%n", name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // do work
                System.out.printf("%s waits%n", name);
                cyclicBarrier.await();
                System.out.printf("%s ends%n", name);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Через `java.util.concurrent.Exchanger` и `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.Exchanger;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConcurrentExchangerHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();

        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, () -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("barrier broken callback starts");
                exchanger.exchange(null);
                System.out.println("barrier broken callback ends");
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        });

        new DoSomethingAndWait("1", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("2", cyclicBarrier).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("3", cyclicBarrier).start();

        // закомментировать строчку, если захочешь,
        // чтобы поменялся порядок вызова exchange()
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        System.out.println("main thread waits, maybe...");
        exchanger.exchange(null);
        System.out.println("main thread ends");
    }

    private static class DoSomethingAndWait extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

        DoSomethingAndWait(String name, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s works%n", name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // do work
                System.out.printf("%s waits%n", name);
                cyclicBarrier.await();
                System.out.printf("%s ends%n", name);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Через `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConcurrentCountDownLatchHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        execute(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("callback");
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        });
    }

    private static void execute(Runnable callback) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        new DoSomethingAndWait("1", countDownLatch).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("2", countDownLatch).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("3", countDownLatch).start();

        // закомментировать строчку, если захочешь,
        // чтобы поменялся порядок выполнения await()
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        System.out.println("main thread awaits");
        countDownLatch.await();
        callback.run();
        System.out.println("main thread ends");
    }

    private static class DoSomethingAndWait extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

        DoSomethingAndWait(String name, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
            this.name = name;
            this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s works%n", name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // do work
                System.out.printf("%s waits%n", name);
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                countDownLatch.await();
                System.out.printf("%s ends%n", name);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Через `java.util.concurrent.Phaser`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConcurrentPhaserHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        execute(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("callback");
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        });
    }

    private static void execute(Runnable callback) throws InterruptedException {
        Phaser phaser = new Phaser(3);

        new DoSomethingAndWait("1", phaser).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("2", phaser).start();
        new DoSomethingAndWait("3", phaser).start();

        // закомментировать строчку, если захочешь,
        // чтобы поменялся порядок выполнения await()
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        System.out.println("main thread awaits, maybe...");
        phaser.awaitAdvance(0);
        callback.run();
        System.out.println("main thread ends");
    }

    private static class DoSomethingAndWait extends Thread {
        private String name;
        private Phaser phaser;

        DoSomethingAndWait(String name, Phaser phaser) {
            this.name = name;
            this.phaser = phaser;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s works%n", name);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // do work
                System.out.printf("%s waits%n", name);
                phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                System.out.printf("%s ends%n", name);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это, скорее, не упрощение, а закрепление факта слома барьера(сколько раз, не важно). У меня же оно считает, сколько раз барьер был сломан.

Comment: А на реализацию через Lock и Condition я бы посмотрел - как раз начинаю ReentrantLock изучать.

Comment: Да, определенно, эту задачу лучше решать через Lock и Condition, так наш главный поток может ждать не только данную задачу! Например, у нас есть два барьера. Тогда, ожидая отклик от первого барьера, мы можем получить отклик от второго! Очень важный момент.

Comment: Если требуется подсчет количества раз, которое барьер был сломан, то можно использовать AtomicInteger, т.е. опять же без Counter.

Comment: И его можно, но всегда же лучше иметь класс, с помощью которого ты не сможешь выстрелить себе в ногу. Например, для counter доступна только операция инкремента(И reset()), да и методы можно оставить несинхронизированными(правда, зачем?) не знаю).

Comment: Кстати, касательно Counter - только сейчас обратил внимание на то, что для потокобезопасности инкремента на поле count в нем нужно добавить модификатор "volatile", а касательно своего собственного класса - я дак, наоборот, не люблю плодить сущности сверх необходимого :)
Также обратите внимание на некоторые мелочи по типу TimUnit, printf и прочие - ими удобнее пользоваться :)

Comment: @Miron, появилось время - накидал выше в ответе всевозможные варианты :)

Comment: Спасибо, что уделили время!

Comment: @Miron, да не за что. Просто сам уже давненько не трогал по-человечески конкурентность в java (в последнее время на работе в архитектуре совсем погряз, поэтому кодингом, к сожалению, занимаюсь куда меньше, чем хотелось бы), поэтому чтобы не терять навыки, периодически мне нужно бы в этом покопаться, да и самому интересно :)

Comment: @Miron, кстати, если вы захотите сохранить логику с вашим Runnable callback'ом в CyclicBarrier, то в примере выше Exchanger, кажется, не так плох (по крайней мере, минимум используемых сущностей) :)

Comment: @Miron, кстати, а вы заметили интересную (но крайне логичную) особенность использования потоков в рамках CyclicBarrier: когда "ломается барьер", то Runnable вызывается именно в том потоке, который своим вызовом cyclicBarrier.await() его сломал (чтобы не плодить новые потоки, это можно проверить например, так: Thread.currentThread().getId()), т.е. пока не выполнится ваш Runnable не продолжится работа даже того потока, который и сломал барьер посредством cyclicBarrier.await().

Comment: Но, с другой стороны, с Exchanger`ом Runnable будет ждать главный поток, если главный поток запаздывает. А на это накладывается тот факт, что Runnable вызывается в последнем вызвавшем await потоке. Хотя, я бы не стал говорить, что запускать Runnable в последнем потоке хорошая идея - если Runnable очень долог, или он чего-то ждёт(wait и тд), то последнему потоку будет худо - он освободится гораздо позже остальных.

Comment: @Miron, я проверил, на самом деле, все остальные потоки, которые ушли в "await()" тоже будут ждать когда исполнится Runnable из CyclicBarrier, т.е. даже не смотря на то, что не в их потоке исполняется Runnable CyclicBarrier'а, они все равно будут ждать его завершения. Скорее всего, там внутренняя блокировка (Lock#unlock), которую ждут все эти потоки отпускается только после того, как исполнится Runnable CyclicBarrier'а.

Comment: Логично. Тогда Exchanger действительно неуместен.

Comment: @Miron, но стоит понимать, что вопрос с блокировкой остальных потоков (за исключением главного, т.е. main) пока они в "await()", до момента завершения исполнения Runnable'а из CyclicBarrier'а никуда не денется и без Exchanger, если в этом Runnable находится какая-то иначе блокирующая/долго исполняемая логика.

Comment: Денется - signal() не задерживает выполнение программы. А exchanger должен ждать "главный поток". Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: @Miron, касательно signal() вы правы, но я имею в виду блокировку исполнения метода run экземпляров класса DoSomethingAndWait (в месте их вызова await()) до момента окончания исполнения Runnable из CyclicBarrier'а (т.е. я делаю акцент на том, что они освободятся не в тот момент, когда вызвался Runnbale, а когда он закончился).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается применением `Lock` и `Condition`.
Что мы получим в итоге? Мы получим счетчик, который будет считать кол-во раз открытия `CyclicBarrier'а`, и возможность узнавать о состоянии этого счетчика атомарно из любого потока. Это полностью решает стоящую перед нами задачу.
Перейдем к реализации.
Во-первых, у нас есть счетчик, его методы необязательно должны быть `synchronized`:

```
class Counter{
    private volatile int count;

    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public void count(){
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    public void reset(){
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

`Runnable`, выполняемый при каждом открытии `CyclicBarrier'а`:

```
Runnable toRunWhenOpen = () -> {
    cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock();
    try{
        counter.count();
        forFirstCyclicBarrier.signal();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        cyclicBarrierMainLock.unlock();
    }
};
```

А вот код в "главном потоке":

```
cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock();
try{
    if(counter.getCount() == 0){
        System.out.println("MAIN waits");
        forFirstCyclicBarrier.await();
    }
} catch(Exception exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    cyclicBarrierMainLock.unlock();
}
```

Видим, что все синхронизировано - `Lock` не даст случится ситуации, описанной в вопросе. Суть программы же заключается в том, что в ходе выполнения возможны только две ситуации:
1) `Runnable` выполнится быстрее. Если "главный поток" доберется до `cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock()` во время выполнения `Runnable`, то он будет послушно ждать освобождения `Lock'а`.
2) Главному потоку придется ждать `Runnable`. Тогда главный поток сначала захватит `Lock`, а потом, как дойдет до `await()`, сразу же отпустит. Вот тогда то `Runnable` и сможет пройти дальше. А как пройдет - даст команду `signal()`, и уже `Runnable` будет ждать, когда "главный поток" дойдет до `unlock()`.

---

Если интересно, вот рабочий вариант, на котором можно проверить работоспособность предложенного способа:

Класс `DoSmthingAndWait`, который является потоком, который "подписывается" на барьер, когда выполняет всю работу:

```
class DoSmthingAndWait extends Thread {
    private String name;
    CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    DoSmthingAndWait(String name, CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " works");
        try {
            sleep(3000); // do work
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(name + " waits");
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(name + " ends");
    }
}
```

Первый сценарий:

```
ReentrantLock cyclicBarrierMainLock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition forFirstCyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrierMainLock.newCondition();
Counter counter = new Counter();
Runnable toRunWhenOpen = () -> {
    cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock();
    try{
        counter.count();
        forFirstCyclicBarrier.signal();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        cyclicBarrierMainLock.unlock();
    }
};
CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(3, toRunWhenOpen);
new DoSmthingAndWait("1", cyclicBarrier).start();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
new DoSmthingAndWait("2", cyclicBarrier).start();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
new DoSmthingAndWait("3", cyclicBarrier).start();

cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock();
try{
    if(counter.getCount() == 0){
        System.out.println("MAIN waits");
        forFirstCyclicBarrier.await();
    }
} catch(Exception exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    cyclicBarrierMainLock.unlock();
}

System.out.println("MAIN ends");
```

Вывод:

> 1 works
>   2 works
>   3 works
>   MAIN waits
>   1 waits
>   2 waits
>   3 waits
>   3 ends
>   2 ends
>   1 ends
>   MAIN ends

Второй сценарий:

Добавьте следующую строку перед `cyclicBarrierMainLock.lock()`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Получите следующий вывод:

> 1 works
>   2 works
>   3 works
>   1 waits
>   2 waits
>   3 waits
>   3 ends
>   2 ends
>   1 ends
>   MAIN ends

Comment: Мне кажется, что Counter избыточен.
В качестве примера без него и упрощения некоторых моментов добавил ответ (можете из него к себе перетащить, да я его удалю).
А еще чуть позднее (сейчас на работе пока не до этого) отпишу аналогичный пример, но через Lock и Condition вместо synchronized и wait/notify.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Сделал через Lock и Condition.

Comment: а у меня только сейчас появилось время, но хотя бы сейчас накидал выше в ответе всевозможные варианты, вдруг какой еще приглянется :)